# Summing sparse matrix rows by column groups

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a scipy sparse matrix in coo format:

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
data = np.asarray([[1, 0, 0], [.8, .2, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]])
data
array([[1. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.8, 0.2, 0. ],
       [0. , 1. , 0. ],
       [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]])
sparse_matrix = coo_matrix(data)
```

For each column I have a cluster assignment, I would like to sum rows grouped by their cluster assignment. During this operation I would like to stay in sparse format for memory issues.

Example:

`labels = ["a", "b", "b"]`

Expected output:

```
1,   0
.8, .2
0,   1
.4, .6
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be approached the same was with dense arrays - for each group, select the desired columns, and sum.  Collect the results.

```
In [2]: data = np.asarray([[1, 0, 0], [.8, .2, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]])
In [3]: M = sparse.csc_matrix(data)
In [4]: M
Out[4]: 
<4x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
In [5]: M.A
Out[5]: 
array([[1. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.8, 0.2, 0. ],
       [0. , 1. , 0. ],
       [0.4, 0.3, 0.3]])
In [6]: M[:,[0]].sum(axis=1)
Out[6]: 
matrix([[1. ],
        [0.8],
        [0. ],
        [0.4]])
In [7]: M[:,[1,2]].sum(axis=1)
Out[7]: 
matrix([[0. ],
        [0.2],
        [1. ],
        [0.6]])
In [8]: res = np.concatenate((Out[6], Out[7]), axis=1)
In [9]: res
Out[9]: 
matrix([[1. , 0. ],
        [0.8, 0.2],
        [0. , 1. ],
        [0.4, 0.6]])
```

Note that the `sum` produces a dense `np.matrix`.  `sparse` does this routinely, I think, because such summations are always denser than the source.  A sum will be 0 only if all the elements are 0 (except for the rare case of a bunch of nonzeros canceling each other out).

Since the column indexing and sum are both implemented as matrix products, it might be possible to speed up the process a bit by constructing a matrix that does both actions at once.  But that's an implementation detail.

Indexing of sparse matrices is pretty slow (compared to dense ones).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I really want to keep my matrices sparse at all times to prevent memory errors later on. The solution I have now chosen is to do the matrix products for each group and then adding each resulting column to an empty lil format matrix. This way I'm keeping my matrices sparse all the way through.